# How to search and replace more than character and a string in vim

Tags: regular-expression, search, replace

I know it should be easy, but somehow I don’t get it right.

I've got a text with **artist_id**, **album_id**,... and want to replace them with just **id**.

How do I do that?

I tried `:%s/[a-z]+_id/id/gc`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 4):

If you read `:help pattern`, you’ll see you need `\+`. Vim’s patterns are not quite like PCRE or POSIX B/ERE

Comment: The escape is in the help tag, too `:help /\+`

Comment: I didn’t know about :help pattern. Thx

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers, look in the docs for `\v` which, at the beginning of the search string, makes it behave as "very magic", which means that `+` will work the way you want, while `\+` will refer to the literal plus sign.

Comment: I was always wondering about that.  Now i know. Thx

Comment: @OswaldoNickel `:help` is your friend, always. You can accept this (or the other) answer, however, as a more effective "thank you" that encourages us to answer better and better everytime.